# MySQL never ending 'Copying to tmp table' with db view and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view, left-join

I have performance issue on MySQL. Database contains about 400 000 records, site run's on Drupal, all collumns have indexes. Unfortunately some adverts don't have all data so I need to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

View:

```
CREATE VIEW cases_view AS SELECT 
    n.nid AS nid,
        n.created AS created,
        n.type AS type,
        n.status AS status,
        i.field_adpersonid_value AS field_adpersonid_value,
        f.field_adpersonname_value AS field_adpersonname_value,
        l.field_adpersonfamilyname_value AS field_adpersonfamilyname_value,
        b.field_adpersondateofborn_value AS field_adpersondateofborn_value,
        d.field_adpersondateofdied_value AS field_adpersondateofdied_value,
        p.field_adnewspapergroupname_value AS field_adnewspapergroupname,
        c.field_sbfcompanyname_value AS field_sbfcompanyname_value
FROM
    node n
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_adpersonname f ON (f.entity_id = n.nid)
JOIN field_data_field_adpersonid i ON (i.entity_id = n.nid)
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_adpersonfamilyname l ON (l.entity_id = n.nid)
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_adpersondateofborn b ON (b.entity_id = n.nid)
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_adpersondateofdied d ON (d.entity_id = n.nid)
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_adnewspapergroupname p ON (p.entity_id = n.nid)
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_sbfcompanyname c ON (c.entity_id = n.nid)
WHERE
   n.type = 'advertisement' AND n.status = 1 AND  `p`.`field_adnewspapergroupname_value` <> 'Times Newspaper'
```

Then I search for data in this view (php) with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.field_adpersonname_value AS field_adpersonname_value, v.field_adpersonid_value AS field_adpersonid_value, v.field_adpersonfamilyname_value AS field_adpersonfamilyname_value, v.field_adpersondateofborn_value AS field_adpersondateofborn_value, v.field_adpersondateofdied_value AS field_adpersondateofdied_value, v.field_sbfcompanyname_value AS field_sbfcompanyname_value
FROM 
cases_view v
WHERE  (v.field_adpersonname_value LIKE 'Sample name%' ESCAPE '\\') AND (v.field_adpersonfamilyname_value LIKE '%' ESCAPE '\\') AND (v.field_adpersondateofborn_value LIKE '%' ESCAPE '\\') AND (v.field_adpersondateofdied_value LIKE '%' ESCAPE '\\') 
ORDER BY v.field_adpersonfamilyname_value ASC, v.field_adpersondateofdied_value DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

My db config:

```
max_connections = 300
connect_timeout = 100
max_user_connections = 300
key_buffer = 256M
query_cache_size = 96MB
query_cache_limit = 4MB
table_cache = 1800
table_definition_cache = 1800
sort_buffer_size = 32M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
tmp_table_size = 64MB
join_buffer_size = 4M
wait_timeout = 60
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 128M
tmp_table_size = 128M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
thread_cache_size = 128
```

After I start mysql server site and search is ligtnign fast but after few hours 'Copy to tmp  table' starts copying more and more data serwer is getting slow and finaly crash. 
System have 8GB of RAM and its dual core.

Please help!

Comment: Try increase the join_buffer_size. Its seems to me that you dont have enough ram. Once the innodb_buffer_pool is full you might run into problems. You couold actually set the innodb_buffer_size to 80 % of your total, so 6 in this case, make sure you increase the log file to minimum 25 % of the innodb_buffer_pool_size. So minimum 2 GB.

Comment: It could also be the query cache. If this is to big it takes time for the service to go trough the chache. Try disable it completley or set it to very low. Btw, does these tables get updated alot?.

Comment: Can you provide a explain from the select query also?

Comment: I posted query explain on google docs to make it more readable:
[Query explain](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AgUUlRsGeeO_dHNmMGs1WXNqTjZHQmk5NVVTclpqb1E&output=html)

Comment: Is there indexes on the fields in the (v.field_adpersonname_value LIKE 'Sample name%' ESCAPE '\\') AND (v.field_adpersonfamilyname_value LIKE '%' ESCAPE '\\') AND (v.field_adpersondateofborn_value LIKE '%' ESCAPE '\\') AND (v.field_adpersondateofdied_value LIKE '%' ESCAPE '\\') 
?

Comment: v is not a table but view so I think its not possible to set indexes on views?

Comment: Explained view query can be found here (google docs): [View query explained](https://docs.google.com/a/exesmedia.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AgUUlRsGeeO_dHNmMGs1WXNqTjZHQmk5NVVTclpqb1E&gid=1)

Comment: The fields in the view are related to table columns. So they can have indexes.

Comment: Tables are update few times a day. Do you think tmp_table_size=64M is enought?

Comment: BTW when I tried to set innodb_log_file_size to 2G I got this error
InnoDB: Error: combined size of log files must be < 4 GB
when I set it to 1900MB it works fine.

Comment: Then it must be because your running on a 32 bit system. Innodb was designed for 32bit hence that limit.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33061/mysql-5-5-innodb-innodb-log-file-size-higher-than-4gb-combined

Comment: Well I'm runnign 64bit system but you are right that InnoDB was designed to work on 32bit so 4G is the limit.

Comment: I seems that tempfs solved my problem (at least for now). I've set 1GB tempfs in RAM and added it to my.cnf tmpdir=/var/tmpfs

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this particular case it might be faster to first lookup the ID's of the lines you want to choose, and then add the other tables. Play with it a bit.

```
select <fields>
from node n
<joins>
where nid in 
  ( select nid 
    from node 
    where n.status = 1 
      and n.type = 'advertisement
  )
```

Another solution, especially if you only need one field from another table is to use subselects, that sounds slow, but are sometimes faster than joins:

```
select n.fields,
  (select field_adpersonid_value from field_data_field_adpersonid i ON i.entity_id = n.nid) as field_adpersonid_value
from node n
where .. etc
```

Also you can try to Explain  to see where it is slow.

Comment: I've solve my problem with tempfs but I think your got the point, and I will give it a try also. Thanks.